# How to keep elements in endstate after CSS animation on :hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm working on an edited version of this giftbox animation: https://codepen.io/RoyLee0702/pen/RwNgVya

However I just cannot seem to find out how to make sure that after the :hover effect takes place, every element is kept as the endstate. When you currently move the mouse, everything will go back to it's initial state. Is there anyone who can easily see what needs to be changed to keep the giftbox open? I want every element to keep the endstate (so the lid, image, box, bowtie, etc.)

On mobile it already works perfect 'out of the box' because the hover effect is replaced by a click. Therefore it doesn't go back to its initial state automatically.

Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
}
.box::before {
  content: "";
  width: 440px;
  height: 440px;
  background-color: #89cff0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.box-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 123.3333333333px;
  background-color: #cc231e;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: linear-gradient(#762c2c,#ff0303);
}
.box-body .img{
  opacity: 0;
  ransform: translateY(0%);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.box-body:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: box-body 1s forwards ease-in-out;
          animation: box-body 1s forwards ease-in-out;
}
.box-body:hover .img{
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateY(-157px);


   
}
.box-body:hover .box-lid {
  -webkit-animation: box-lid 1s forwards ease-in-out;
          animation: box-lid 1s forwards ease-in-out;
}
.box-body:hover .box-bowtie::before {
  -webkit-animation: box-bowtie-left 1.1s forwards ease-in-out;
          animation: box-bowtie-left 1.1s forwards ease-in-out;
}
.box-body:hover .box-bowtie::after {
  -webkit-animation: box-bowtie-right 1.1s forwards ease-in-out;
          animation: box-bowtie-right 1.1s forwards ease-in-out;
}
.box-body::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff,#ffefa0)
}
.box-lid {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #cc231e;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.box-lid::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ffefa0,#fff)
}
.box-bowtie {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
.box-bowtie::before, .box-bowtie::after {
  content: "";
  width: 83.3333333333px;
  height: 83.3333333333px;
  border: 16.6666666667px solid white;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 99%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box-bowtie::before {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) skew(10deg, 10deg);
          transform: translateX(-100%) skew(10deg, 10deg);
}
.box-bowtie::after {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
          transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes box-lid {
  0%,
  42% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-85%, -230%, 0) rotate(-25deg);
            transform: translate3d(-85%, -230%, 0) rotate(-25deg);
  }
  90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-119%, 225%, 0) rotate(-70deg);
            transform: translate3d(-119%, 225%, 0) rotate(-70deg);
  }
}

@keyframes box-lid {
  0%,
  42% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-85%, -230%, 0) rotate(-25deg);
            transform: translate3d(-85%, -230%, 0) rotate(-25deg);
  }
  90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-119%, 225%, 0) rotate(-70deg);
            transform: translate3d(-119%, 225%, 0) rotate(-70deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes box-body {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 25%, 0) rotate(20deg);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 25%, 0) rotate(20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, -15%, 0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate3d(0%, -15%, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes box-body {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 25%, 0) rotate(20deg);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 25%, 0) rotate(20deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, -15%, 0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate3d(0%, -15%, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes box-bowtie-right {
  0%,
  50%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -15%) rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translate(-50%, -15%) rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}
@keyframes box-bowtie-right {
  0%,
  50%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -15%) rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translate(-50%, -15%) rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes box-bowtie-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
  50%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -15%) rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translate(-50%, -15%) rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
}
@keyframes box-bowtie-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
  50%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -15%) rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translate(-50%, -15%) rotate(45deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
            transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(0deg) skew(10deg, 10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="text-center text-light my-5"><strong>Hover the box</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
          <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          <div class="box-lid">
            
            <div class="box-bowtie"></div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:hover` is an element state that's no longer invoked after `mouseout` so it's expected to revert to original attributes as such. For what you describe you could attach a `mouseover` event listener with javascript and apply the effects as a separate added class on hover so it's persistent. Then your `forwards` would behave how you're hoping.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!